# Wilson confidence rating calculator

Tags: script, voting

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

The [Wilson confidence rating](https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) provides an alternative way to rate answers and questions, which may be more meaningful than just the number of upvotes minus the number of downvotes. This script provides that rating, upon request [here](https://stackapps.com/q/8555/34061).

### Download

It's a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) which means you need a userscript *manager* installed in your browser if you don't have one already. Just Google for Violentmonkey or Tampermonkey, how to install them depends on your browser.

The script itself can be installed via [this link](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/raw/master/wilson-calculator/wilson-calculator.user.js); source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/wilson-calculator/wilson-calculator.user.js).

If you have the [privilege to see vote counts](https://stackapps.com/help/privileges/established-user), the rating will automatically be added if you click the post score. If you don't, the script will fetch the vote count from the API, and you need to click the 'Wilson' button for one of the posts on the page.

### Platform

Tested with Violentmonkey in Firefox on macOS, but it's likely to work on all browsers and platforms. (Please let me know if it doesn't!)